# how to create a web Bookmark with thumbnails android widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget, bookmarks

Could anybody know how to make web bookmark with thumbnails? please give me an idea on how to get the thumbnails or screen shoots of current bookmark websites..

this is the widget that I would like to learn..
[image]

Comment: For ICS+, thumbnails are also stored in bookmarks database by the browser.

Comment: I couldn't get Browser.BookMarkColumns.THUMBNAIL.. is there any other way?

Comment: I've explained that in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is for ICS+ only :

Browser API is being revamped along the lines of Contacts API, now bookmarks are linked to Accounts and also have a folder structure.As far as I know, new Internals have not been exposed via public API calls, and all implementations are likely to be changed in future, and your App might stop working then, if you use internal API. Still, its worth while to know internal workings of android browser provider:

In [`BrowserProvider2`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#BrowserProvider2) . Now, thumbnails are in a different table, and have their own  [URI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#226). But internally, they are placing data in images table, this also has a [URI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#222).

Have a look at structure of new [Bookmarks table](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#401) and [Thumbnails table](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#474) and [Images table](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#437). Then , see how bookmarks are being inserted :

- [Legacy calls](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#1371)
- [Bookmarks insert](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#1386)
- [Extraction of thumbnails etc](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#2033)
- [Extracted Images insertion](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#1429)

Also, [`BrowserContract`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/provider/BrowserContract.java#BrowserContract) has these columns defined as [`ImageColumns`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/provider/BrowserContract.java#186) these store, thumbnails, favicon, and touch icons etc.

Finally, [`query()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#877) has matches for  [`IMAGES`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#1069) (no id, url is primary key) and [`THUMBNAILS`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#1104) (with id).

So, from here you can get whatever images you need using new [`CONTENT_URI`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/provider/BrowserContract.java#BrowserContract.Bookmarks.0CONTENT_URI) of [`BrowserContract`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/provider/BrowserContract.java#BrowserContract), append it with [URI's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/browser/provider/BrowserProvider2.java#202) of Images,Thumbnails etc and run your queries/inserts .

Comment: So now I have an answer my question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725192/how-can-i-get-set-bookmarks-per-account-on-android
Thanks

Comment: @Pascal Great work!. May I suggest that you split it to question and answer, its OK to answer your own questions after a research.

Answer (score 0):

I think for thumbnails you put your link on webView and save your webView under bitmap. Then you save bitmap on SD card and your have your thumbnail.

You can get bookmarks like this :

```
Cursor mCur  = ActivityChooseBookmark.this.getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                        projection, Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, null, null);
```

Use this to get your bitmap from webView :

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) 
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else 
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Now just save it on SD and it's done

Comment: I am referring to the browser API thumbnail.. any idea? thanks! =)

Comment: I don't know other way to create thumbnail :/ sorry. Do you have a link to this API ? Never find this kind of API